# Rule cannot be matched in Flex (LEX) when using ^

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex, lexer

I'm trying to run some simple regex in Flex but I cannot get the operator "^" to work as a negation.
This is my code:`

```
%%


[^abc]      printf("rule triggered\n");
.       
\n
```

It should just match any character that is not "a", "b" or "c", but instead I get a:
"warning, rule cannot be matched".

The other uses for "^" seem to work fine, ^a matches any string that starts with "a" and [a^b] matches any string that contains "a" or "b". Also, strangely enough the rule [^a] works as expected if preceded by something else, such as:

```
%%

b+[^a]      printf("rule triggered\n");
.
\n
```

This matches a string that begins with any number of "b"s that are not followed by an "a" and seems to work correctly. But it won't work if I allow zero occurences of "b" as in:

```
%%
 
b*[^a]      printf("rule triggered\n");
.       
\n
```

This gives the same "warning, rule cannot be matched" and sure enough, doesn't work. Kinda stumped here.

ps. I'm using Flex  in cycgwin if that matters (it should be compatible with all Lex syntax).

`

Comment: Other than producing the warning, in what way does it not work as you expect? I'm assuming you want the line "rule triggered" to be printed once less per line than it actually is. Is that right?

Comment: I just noticed that it kept triggering even when I used "a", "b" and "c" so I assumed that it wasn't matching that particular rule. Your comment just made me realize that it wasn't matching the rule for "\n", which means that "a" followed by the return was triggering the rule because "\n" is in fact not "a", "b" nor "c". Putting the rule for "\n" on the first line fixes the warning and gives me the behavior I expected. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's the rule `\n` that can't match anything. It can't match anything because a newline character is not an `a`, a `b` nor a `c`, so it will always match the first rule and thus the third rule cannot every match.